# Create mysql query for different day intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has these fields.
booking_date, leaving_date
A customer can book a hotel for from 1 day to one year.
I need count for how many days someone booked hotels for different day interval. 
Days interval can be like this:

```
1-7 days
7-14 days
15-30 days
31-45 days
46-60 days
61-90 days
91-120 days
121-180 days
```

I can get the count for booking for any days by this query.

```
select DATEDIFF( booking_date,leaving_date) as day_diff 
from hotel_booking 
group by day_diff;
```

But not able to create a query for different days interval as mention above. I also need these count group by monthly basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your existing query in another one using conditional aggregation to give you the counts for each period length:

```
SELECT SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 1 AND 7) AS `1 to 7 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 8 AND 14) AS `8 to 14 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 15 AND 30) AS `15 to 30 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 31 AND 45) AS `31 to 45 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 46 AND 60) AS `46 to 60 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 61 AND 90) AS `61 to 90 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 91 AND 120) AS `91 to 120 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 121 AND 180) AS `121 to 180 days`
FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(booking_date, leaving_date) AS day_diff
      FROM hotel_booking) dd
```

To group the values by booking month, change the query to

```
SELECT MONTH(booking_date) AS booking_month,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 1 AND 7) AS `1 to 7 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 8 AND 14) AS `8 to 14 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 15 AND 30) AS `15 to 30 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 31 AND 45) AS `31 to 45 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 46 AND 60) AS `46 to 60 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 61 AND 90) AS `61 to 90 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 91 AND 120) AS `91 to 120 days`,
       SUM(day_diff BETWEEN 121 AND 180) AS `121 to 180 days`
FROM (SELECT DATEDIFF(booking_date, leaving_date) AS day_diff
      FROM hotel_booking) dd
GROUP BY booking_month
ORDER BY booking_month
```

Comment: Thank you reply. I also need these count on a monthly basis. group by booking date. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1791574 See my edit. I think that will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can put these values in separate *row* by doing:

```
select (case when booking_date < leaving_date + interval 
7 day then '1-7 day'
             when booking_date < leaving_date + interval 
14 day then '7-14 day'
             . . .
        end) as diff,
       count(*) 
from hotel_booking 
group by diff;
```

Comment: Thank you reply. I also need these count on a monthly basis. group by booking date. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    SUM(day_diff >= 1   AND day_diff <= 7)   `1-7 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 8   AND day_diff <= 14)  `8-14 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 15  AND day_diff <= 30)  `15-30 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 31  AND day_diff <= 45)  `31-45 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 46  AND day_diff <= 60)  `46-60 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 61  AND day_diff <= 90)  `61-90 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 91  AND day_diff <= 120) `91-120 days`,
    SUM(day_diff >= 121 AND day_diff <= 180) `121-180 days`
FROM (
    SELECT DATEDIFF( booking_date,leaving_date) day_diff FROM hotel_booking 
) x
```

This will give you a unique record with the counts by duration in columns.

You actually only need to aggregate once : I moved the aggregation from your original query to the outer query.

Comment: Thank you reply. I also need these count on a monthly basis. group by booking date. Is it possible?